# how to make sure user type correct type in form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I found this example on w3schools website -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Can Validate Input</h2>

<p>Please input a number between 1 and 10:</p>

<input id="numb">

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x, text;

  // Get the value of the input field with id="numb"
  x = document.getElementById("numb").value;

  // If x is Not a Number or less than one or greater than 10
  if (isNaN(x) || x < 1 || x > 10) {
    text = "Input not valid";
  } else {
    text = "Input OK";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

- when I input 9 - it says 'Input OK'
- when I input 11 -it says 'Input not valid'

but I have following questions -

- how can I force users to type the correct type I want, but if they don't, then don't allow them to submit or re-input.

Comment: change the if condition that requires a range of values to what suits your needs. Please note that this js is not necessary if you use an input of type number with a min and max attribute. Have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) for info

Comment: Yes, it will be suggested to use `input type number`.  But what I've seen in `min` and `max` cases is that only if the user uses up and down arrow keys to change the value, this restriction works but the user can still type any number (out of range also). So, if you want to control that, you can have an `onChange` handler on your input and on every change check if the value is out of range and change it back to max/min. For example if value is 12, you can change it back to 10 as it is the maximum here.

Answer (score 1):

you are compareing string with number!
you should parse `x` to an integer like:

```
x = parseInt(document.getElementById("numb").value);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to listen to changes on the input for instance. One way, just changing the code in the example above is to switch to listen to changes on the number field as trigger to validate:

```
<input id="numb" onChange="myFunction()">

<button type="button" >Submit</button>
```

Then you can add more logic into the myFunction() to make sure the button can't be pressed until numbers are valid and so on, see a working example that stops the user from pressing the button until input is valid:

https://jsfiddle.net/5fg4payk/2/

Answer (score 1):

like this `<input type="number" id="numb"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're wanting range restriction you can achieve this with the [HTML5 constraint validation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#validating_forms_using_javascript) in combination with `type="number"`, `min="1"` and `max="10"`.

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="10" step="1" id="numb" oninput="(validity.valid)||(value='');">
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent re-input, you need to disable the field.

`document.getElementById("numb").disabled = true;`

So your code becomes :

```
if (isNaN(x) || x < 1 || x > 10) {
    text = "Input not valid";
    document.getElementById("numb").disabled = true;
  } else {
    text = "Input OK";
  }
```